# Remove Plastic Bracing by a Window

Tags: windows, removal

I apologize if I'm abusing terminology, I'm not completely sure the correct names for window anatomy.

I'm trying to remove a plastic brace that's adjacent to a window and I can't figure out why it won't budge.

There's a silicone seal between the brace and the window casing, which I've broken to the best of my knowledge. It is L-shaped to wrap around the drywall. Still when I try to pull the brace out it refuses to move.

Any thoughts on how I can figure out the issue or remove the brace are appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to remove it ?

Answer (score 1):

That is a drywall trim piece and it hooks back around behind the drywall which is why it is not budging. The only way to remove it is to remove the drywall. For your purposes, you could continue to break off the outside visible leg and then cut off any left over exposed pieces with a razor knife

[image]